# Constexpr and array

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr

Consider the following code snippet (of course this piece of code is not useful at all but I've simplified it just to demonstrate my question) :

```
constexpr std::array<char*, 5> params_name
{
    "first_param",
    "second_param",
    "third_param",
    "fourth_param",
    "fifth_param"
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> a_vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < params_name.size(); ++i) {
        a_vector.push_back(params_name[i]);
    }
}
```

I would like to be sure understanding what happens to the for loop during compilation. Is the loop unrolled and becomes ? :

```
a_vector.push_back("first_param")
a_vector.push_back("second_param")
a_vector.push_back("third_param")
a_vector.push_back("fourth_param")
a_vector.push_back("fifth_param")
```

If it's the case, is the behaviour identical regardless the number of elements contained in the params_name array ? If yes, then I'm wondering whether it could be more interesting just to store those values in a regular array built at run time to avoid code expansion ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens to the loop is entirely up to the compiler. The compiler is free to unroll the loop in this manner, but is not required to. The compiler can simply generate unoptimized code. The compiler can do different things depending on the compilation options. The C++ standard allows the compiler to make any optimization, as long as there are no observable effects of the optimization.

Comment: You're using `std::array`, so why not iterate over it properly rather than presume there's 5 entries?

Comment: I think in this case you have simplified it to the point where you are correct that there is no reason. The advantages of std::array over C arrays are basically that they fit the STL container metaphors, so you only have to learn one thing. In this case, for example, you could rewrite the for as for(auto param: params_name), which you couldn't do so easily with a C array.

Comment: @tadman : I've edited my code.

Comment: @Ron : compile fine in VS2015 though !

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik : I don't understand however how it would work during run time if the loop has not been unrolled ? The array would have to be initialized at run time right, bypassing the use of the 'constexpr' keyword then ?

Comment: @Gem Taylor : the point of the question is about the use of constexpr, not about the use of std::array over a rough C style array ;)

Comment: "as long as there are no observable effects". A `constexpr` object is not etched in stone. There is no requirement, whatsoever, that the contents of the `constexpr` object are hardcoded into the executable. The C++ compiler is free to generate code that uses a random number generator until it randomly produces the contents of the `constexpr` object, ***as long as there are no observable effects***. That is, as long as your application, your code, at runtime, cannot "observe" the contents of the incomplete object. As long as it is not possible for the code to "see" the incomplete object.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that at present `std::array` isn't constexpr-enabled. You can work around this by simply using a regular array such as

```
constexpr char const * const my_array[5] = { /* ... */ };
```

As for your question:

All `constexpr` really means is "this value is known at compile time".

> Is the loop unrolled and becomes ?

I don't know. It depends on your compiler, architecture, standard library implementation, and optimization settings. I wouldn't think about this too much. You can be confident that at reasonable optimization levels (-O1 and -O2) your compiler will weigh the benefits and drawbacks of doing this vs not, and pick **a good option**.

> If it's the case, is the behaviour identical regardless the number of elements contained in the params_name array ?

Yes! It doesn't matter whether the compiler unrolls the loop. When your code runs, it will appear to behave exactly like what you wrote. This is called the "as-if" rule, meaning that no matter what optimizations the compiler does, the resulting program must behave "as-if" it does what you wrote (assuming your code doesn't invoke undefined behavior).

> could be more interesting just to store those values in a regular array built at run time to avoid code expansion?

From where would these values come if you did? From standard input? From a file? If yes, then the compiler can't know what they will be or how many there will be, so it has little choice but to make a runtime loop. If no, then even if the array is not `constexpr`, the compiler is likely smart enough to figure out what you mean and optimize the program to be the same as with a `constexpr` array.

To summarize: don't worry about things like loop unrolling or code duplication. Modern compilers are pretty smart and will usually generate the right code for your situation. The amount of extra memory spent on loop unrolling like this is usually more than offset by the performance improvements. Unless you're on an embedded system where every byte matters, just don't worry about it.